# FatalErrorException Class 'App\friendships' not found after uploading laravel site to host

Tags: php, laravel-5

Not sure how to go about asking this question,

When in developer mode in my local environment (vlindr.dev)
I get no errors whatsoever.
but after i uploaded it to my server, and I try to log in (after creating an account)

it gives a FatalErrorException Class 'App\friendships'
in 6829641978a8e79623101cad68448ef9d64f3b29.php (line 50)
(in console->> dashboard:1 GET http://vlindr.com/dashboard 500 (Internal Server Error) )

when i click on 6829641978a8e79623101cad68448ef9d64f3b29.php
it redirects me to vlindr.com/requests ( in console -->> requests:1 GET http://vlindr.com/requests 500 (Internal Server Error))

it probably is a spelling mistake somewhere ( but as far as I can see everywhere where the 'App\Friendships' is called it seems to be in order)

Anybody that knows how to solve this, your help is very much appreciated, I'm not sure what part of my code I should post so any suggestions on that part and I will gladly add it here.

Comment: youe localhost is windows  and your server is linux?

Comment: as far as I know both are windows?

Comment: check for sure  ..  because this could be an real reason .. any way check if you have some call to Friendships class in lowercase and update with uppercase

Comment: Running `composer dumpautoload` *may* help. If you were using linux, I'd suggest doing a search with grep `grep -R 'App\friendships' app/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  referring to  `'App\friendships'`   (with friendships il lovercase)   but you are using

```
 'App\Friendships'  // as Class  with Firts Capitalized  F
```

Windows  files name are case insensitive but Linux are case sensitive

Comment: yes, the error that is thrown is App\friendships, 
and I am calling App\Friendships everywhere that it is needed.. but not sure how to go about finding where in requests.blade.php App\friendships(withlowercase) is called.

Comment: my is a suggestion  .. only you can assess whether the suggestion is useful or not

Comment: Thank you, it was a spelling mistake in my navbar for the notifications of any friendship requests

        {{App\Friendships::where('status', 0)->where.. was set in lowercase.